# Controlling mixing with an oscillator or lfo

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'have two oscillators with different waveshape (triangular and square):

```
var oscTri = audioCtx.createOscillator(); 
var oscSqu = audioCtx.createOscillator();
oscTri.type = 'triangle';
oscSqu.type = 'square';
var mixTri = audioCtx.createGain();
var mixSqu = audioCtx.createGain();
oscTri.connect(this.mixTri);
oscSqu.connect(this.mixSqu);
mixTri.connect(audioCtx.destination);
mixSqu.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

I'd like to control the mixing of the two with a third oscillator so the output sound will oscillate between the two (when gain of triangle is 1, square is 0; when triangle is 0.5, square is 0.5, triangle is 0.75, square is 0.25; and so on):

```
var modOsc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
```

How I can connect this modulator oscillator to have an "oscillation" between the two previous waveforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set mixtri = 1 and mixSqu = -1 then connect the modOSC to the gains gain value that should to the trick. Personally i would use filters cause i like it more i made and example for you at https://gtube.de my site click on the PUBLISH / SYNTHY DATABASE on your example. Than press the Letter A to hear the effect. You can see the setup on the Synthesizer Tab. My site doesn't work with the gain nodes because they are not fixed => It allows more than one key to be pressed. But with only gain nodes it should work as well.

Cheers

Kilian